# Horizontal colorbar over 2 of 3 subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axes, colorbar

does someone know how to elegantly draw a horizontal colorbar over two of three subplots and one additional horizontal colorbar over the third subplot.

Ideally, the colorbars should have the same x-dimensions as the corresponding image axis. I did not find any nice solution, except setting up an entire image grid using `matplotlib.gridspec`.

Drawing single colorbars works perfectly fine with `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.ImageGrid`, but it fails when trying to draw a colorbar over two of three axes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea is to use `fig.add_axes` to add the axes where the colorbar will be.
Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.random.random((10, 10, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(12, 3))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.85)
for i in range(3):
    im = ax[i].imshow(matrix[:, :, i], interpolation='nearest')
    ax[i].set_aspect("equal")

plt.draw()
p0 = ax[0].get_position().get_points().flatten()
p1 = ax[1].get_position().get_points().flatten()
p2 = ax[2].get_position().get_points().flatten()
ax_cbar = fig.add_axes([p0[0], 0, p1[2]-p0[0], 0.05])
plt.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cbar, orientation='horizontal')

ax_cbar1 = fig.add_axes([p2[0], 0, p2[2]-p2[0], 0.05])
plt.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cbar1, orientation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

[image: example_colorbar]

**Edit:**
The documentation of `fig.add_axes` say:

> Add an axes at position *rect* [*left*, *bottom*, *width*,
>   *height*] where all quantities are in fractions of figure
>   width and height.

So to put the colorbar on top of the graphs you only need to change the `bottom` argumen to 1.

From

```
ax_cbar = fig.add_axes([p0[0], 0, p1[2]-p0[0], 0.05])
ax_cbar1 = fig.add_axes([p2[0], 0, p2[2]-p2[0], 0.05])
```

to

```
ax_cbar = fig.add_axes([p0[0], 1, p1[2]-p0[0], 0.05])
ax_cbar1 = fig.add_axes([p2[0], 1, p2[2]-p2[0], 0.05])
```

[image]

Comment: that looks almost exactly how i want it. If now you tell me how to put the colorbar on top of the graphs, it would be perfect.

Comment: @F.Win ok! I add a simple example.

Comment: For some reason when I save the image, I get an empty (and transparent) image. MPL version: 3.5.0